# PHP framework class - How to initiate classes via class

Tags: php, subclass

I usually setup a initial class on a website called something like baseFrame, which holds all the basics functions.  (MVC style)

Now, I realized I was having issues calling the baseFrame from classes called throughout the website (the baseFrame has a function called callClass, which I was using to include and running the new class that extends from the base.  I realized that you can't call a extended class under a function, because it's unable to read the parent class.

So, I wrote a new script called "callfunction.php" which was not a class base it self, it was a straight function that called the extended class, which calls the baseFrame correctly.  Now this method worked, I however am not used to not using classes.  Is there something I'm missing? Would I rather call a new class from within the baseFrame class? Is that possible? Again, running a class within the baseFrame class didn't allow me to call the extended at all...So I'm guessing that isn't technically possible?

Comment: could you provide a piece of code :)

Comment: From your description it sounds like you are missing a couple of concepts. For instance, in MVC there is nothing "holding all the functions". In fact, something "holding all the functions" sounds like a God object and that is an Antipattern you should avoid. Show some code please.

Comment: Would love to provide some code, but there is way way to many documents lol.  Gordon, you're exactly right, I got used to doing a "God Object" style for a while, but recently changed my ways into the MVC style world.  So it's normal / okay / alright from a developers end to have a function outside of a class (for initiating classes at least)? Thanks!

Comment: do not reinvent the wheel, we already have tires.

Comment: If I was convinced you mean a Factory pattern by "have a function outside of a class (for initiating classes at least)", I'd say yes, but I am not sure this is what you got there in your code base.

Answer (score -2):

may be this resources help.
there are many frameworks to build secure and reliable systems.

note: mvc is just one solution.

[http://framework.zend.com/](http://framework.zend.com)

[http://wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com/) (extensible via plugins)

http://www.codeigniter.com/

Comment: Zend.com is just the website of the company. You mean Zend Framework. Wordpress is not using MVC at all and is known for it's horrible codebase. Code Igniter is well suited for beginners but not exactly known for it's pretty codebase either and they are not getting MVC right as well.

Comment: I would use Zend, but I like writing my own classes from scratch.  I feel as if I'm able to learn and understand more.

Comment: zend.com -> downloads -> there it is. (http://www.zend.com/de/community/downloads).
wordpress needs to be extended not changed, so the codebase is not relevant.

Comment: ZF has a dedicated website with lots of resources, so why not link to the appropriate page instead? WP cannot be properly extended - not in the OO sense - because it's codebase is not following the Open/Closed principle, nor any other OO design principles. WP can only be hacked. So yes, the codebase is very much relevant.